# Translate Delphi XOR to Oracle XOR

Tags: oracle

There's an application written in Delphi, and I'm supposed to write the same encryption in Oracle. I googled a lot for a solution, but got nothing useful. Here's the Delphi code:

```
function Encrypt(tr : string): string;
   var i: Integer;
   Temp: string;

   begin
     for i := 1 to Length(tr) do
     Temp := Temp + Chr(Ord(tr[i]) xor 13);

     result := Temp;
   end;
```

Which results `]l~~` if you pass `Pass` as the parameter when calling.

Here's what I tried:

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1284001741333

http://db-oracl.blogspot.hu/2008/05/bitwise-operation-example-and-or-xor.html

Ps.: This is needed for a stored procedure, and I've been asked to not write extra functions, so I should include everything in the procedure. This makes it harder, since as far as I know there's no built-in XOR function in Oracle (only AND). Thank you for your help!

**EDIT:** Let me ask in another way. Found some implementation method, just like which is linked as the duplication of my question, but have no clue how to implement it in the right way. At the other question I suppose the user who asked had knowledge with Oracle, which I don't have, as this is my first task in Oracle, and I'm totally stuck.

Comment: Your edit doesn't change the fact that this question is a duplicate. If you don't know anything about Oracle, you need to start at the beginning. Get a good text and learn the basics. But you cannot expect us to teacg you that, that is not what Stack Overflow is about. If you don't know Oracle you can't ask us to do you entire work task for you. What you really should be doing is asking your employer to train you properly. If they won't do that perhaps you need to be looking elsewhere.

Comment: I'm not totally new, but have not too much knowledge. I know and you are right, but I have no time now as this is an SOS task, I've to finish it in a few hours. Otherwise, I'd spend as much time as I can on reading a lot more about it. I'd really appreciate if someone could give me a working example, which at least converts `P` to `]`, I think I could finish the rest.

Comment: @Nicholas Krasnov You reopened because you didn't like the answers at the dupe. But that's not how duplicate voting is intended to work. If you think a better answer can be given, add it at the other question, and leave this question closed. There is value to be had in linking questions as duplicates. If two questions ask exactly the same thing, they are duplicates. Thank you for putting it right! You might add your answer to the dupe since it looks more comprehensive than the existing `utl_raw` answer.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Yes I read that. I wanted to make the point that even if there had been no `utl_raw` answer at the dupe, reopening here would not have been correct. Answering there is the correct thing to do. I still think that you should do so. You wrote a good answer and it deserves to be seen.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks David. `UTL_RAW` is already mentioned there. My answer will bring nothing new.

Comment: depending of Delphi version string/char/pchar might be absolutely different types, which would affect bitwise operations.

Comment: @Arioch'The We are talking about an Oracle stored procedure

Comment: I wish you haven't closed it as @NicholasKrasnov 's solution worked like charm, and I think he would deserve his answer to be accepted as this case was (I think) different compared to the other one. Thank you for your help, I'll analyze your code for sure later :)